# C# auto type in console a command

Tags: c#, command

My program interface is a console `cmd`
I added console command (it works fine when iI use it in the console):

```
 stop 0
```

I have a `CommandManager` and when I type in the console

```
stop 0
```

and  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  --> it appears like:

```
CommandManager > stop 0
```

How can i make the program auto type this command for me?

```
if(value1 == 0)
{
      //Console.WriteLine("Command: stop {0}", value1);
      //stop 0
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you're trying to do, and where you encountered issues trying to do that?

Comment: what do you want to type? `CommandManager > stop 0` or the `if` statement?

Comment: the if statement, but the if statement with Console.WriteLine is not recognized as a user imput

Comment: i only want to auto type "stop 0" I need to simulate user imput

Comment: do you want to read a value from the user?

Comment: no the value1 is a trigger

Comment: do you want to display "stop 0" whenever `value1 == 0`?

Comment: yes, any ideea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to display the `value1`

```
if(value1 == 5)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Command: Stop {0}", value1);
      //Stop 5
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
if(value1 == 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("stop 0");
   //stop 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(value1 == 5)
{
      Console.Writeline("Command: Stop 0")
      stop 0
}
```

Comment: My guess is `stop 0` doesn't compile and it isn't clear what your answer actually is.

Comment: Pretty sure 0 is a command line parameter and has nothing to do with the code above in question

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra on reflection, you're correct. Good call.